# Multiprocessing? Threading? infinite loops? what should I do?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, while-loop, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand the most effective way of solving the following issue. I have python code pooling in data from multiple sources (using pyserial). My goal is to generate a pandas table containing all this data that I have collected (from three sources). All the data has to be collected simultaneously so I will either have to use threading or multiprocessing and be able to have all the programs start and stop simultaneously. This is the general idea of my code:

```
User_inputs
###########
functions
###########
Port/Serial Misc.
###########
loops (can be defined in functions) e.g:

def lightloop():
   data = { 'light': []}
   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[ 'light'])
   while True:
       arduino.reset_input_buffer()
       value = float(str(arduino.readline()))#everysecond
       df = df.append({'light': value}, ignore_index=True)
       print df
       time.sleep(1)
       if len(df.index) > 5:
           break  
   return df

###########
code that will analyze the data collected in the loops e.g

datatime = {'time': []}        
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datatime, columns=[ 'time'])
for i in range(len(df['light'])):      
    df2 = df2.append({'time': i}, ignore_index=True)
    df['time'] = df2['time']

print df
df.to_csv('~/Downloads/test.csv', sep='\t')
plt.scatter(df['time'], df['light'])
afont = {'fontname':'Avenir Book'}
mfont = {'fontname':'Menlo Regular'}
plt.title('',**mfont)
plt.ylabel('light', **afont)
plt.xlabel('Time [Second]', **afont)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.savefig(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/test.png'), dpi = 150)
```

What would  be the best way of going about this? I have looked into threading and it isn't very straightforward and complicates my code greatly, I'm also unable to stop the threads such that my data analysis code runs.

Comment: Your use of data-frames here is incredibly inefficient and is going to slow you down tremendously. Grow your data as a list, then create a data-frame at the end. It seems you only want to use the data-frames to create csv's. That's like using a sledgehammer for a nail. Just use the `csv` module and vanilla python data-structures.

Comment: Yes, I agree, i admit it is a bit foolish, I will update this question once I have finished